# NSLocalizedString - build failed

Tags: iphone, nslocalizedstring

I am adding a localized string in **localizable.string**  (English and Norwegian )

in English

```
//of
"of"="of"
```

in Norwegian

```
//of
"of" = "på";
```

When I build application, I get:

> /myPath/nb.lproj/Localizable.strings:0: error: validation failed: The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.

I know that I am getting error due to **på** because when I changed **på** to something else say **p**, build succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert your Norwegian Localizable.strings to UTF-16 encoding. You can convert a file in Xcode in the File inspector (right side bar in XCode), under Text Settings changing the Text Encoding drop-down to UTF-16.

Also here: http://rndm-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/03/objective-cxcode-4-encoding-problem.html

Comment: Saved me quite the headache with my Italian translation that was skipping translations too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remember to finish the line with a semi-colon. `;`

Answer (score 2):

Hum... Norwegian is included in UTF8.

You surely have an encoding problem. It's strange, i never face that with localisables...

However, becareful, you have a syntax error in your english localisable : you must finish every line with **;**

```
"of"="of";
```